# Upgrading Quarto CLI for RStudio on Windows 10

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, upgrade, quarto

I'm using RStudio 2022.07.0 Build 545 (RStudio 2022.07.0-preview+545) on Windows  [Version 10.0.22000.739]. However, when on launching RStudio, I get the following message:

[image]

> Quarto CLI version 0.9.165 is installed, however RStudio requires version 0.9.230.

I tried the Quarto CLI upgrading method given [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli) without any success. How can I solve this?

Comment: Look at https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/ -- the current version listed there is 0.9.637, and it has a downloadable installer.  (Now, for whatever reason at the Release section https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/releases/tag/v0.9.637 that is called a preview.  Just ignore the 'preview' tag and run it.

Comment: I would also check if you already have a quarto version installed and if you get a specific installation in your PATH. The preview version of the IDE you have should ship with a much higher version than 0.9.165, but if a `quarto` is found in PATH it will use this version. So it seems to me you may have one available through your PATH with an older version. I would check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloading the latest version of `Quarto CLI 1.1.189 (Windows)` for the  link
[Quarto CLI 1.1.189 (Windows)](https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/)
solved the issue.